# SecureSocket.isSupported == false

Tags: actionscript-3, security, sockets

I try to use SecureSocket but SecureSocket.isSupported == false.
When I use simple Socket everything is ok.

Did anybody use SecureSocket?

here is my code:
    Security.allowDomain('*');
                Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");
                Security.loadPolicyFile("xmlsocket://" + host + ':' + port +     "/crossdomain.xml");

```
            if(SecureSocket.isSupported)
            {
                c = new SecureSocket();
                receiveBuffer = new ByteArray();
                receiveBuffer.endian = Endian.LITTLE_ENDIAN;

                c.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, closeHandler);
                c.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
                c.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);

                c.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, connectHandler);
            }

            else
            {
                try
                {
                    c = new SecureSocket();
                }
                catch(e:Error)
                {
                    trace(e.toString());
                }
        }
```

Later I have error:
[SWF] /assets/flash/ssl/Main.swf - 63,146 bytes after decompression
Error: Request for resource at tlssocket://game9.lgr.su:8081 by requestor from https://game9.lgr.su/assets/flash/ssl/Main.swf has failed because the server cannot be reached.

*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
Connection to game9.lgr.su:8081 halted - not permitted from https://game9.lgr.su/assets/flash/ssl/Main.swf

Comment: Here is crossdomain from server:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
    <cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" secure="true"/>
    </cross-domain-policy>

Comment: did you find your answer?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on server side. Our server side on Node JS was listening for NOT SECURE SOCKET but was getting SECURE connection. So when server responded with NOT encrypted content Socket on client side just closed.
So make better server.